# How to use inputted text with quickly

Tags: application-development, python, gtk, quickly

I just need the code necessary to have my application assign the input from a text box to a variable after 'Enter' is pushed, and then use it to change a label.

This is what I have for this problem:

```
def on_action_activated(self):
    self.next = self.action.get_text()
```

And then for using it I'm doing:

```
info.set_text("Would you like to start a new game? (no saving yet, working on it...)")
```

And it's not working for me. Now I'm doing all of this in several different functions, so would that be causing the problem, or is it just something else? I have created the local variable for both the label and the text box.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have access to the code I used to do it now, but if you have created your local variable for the text box, with the `self.textbox = builder.get_object('glade texbox id')` (or something like that), you should be able to do `on_textbox_activated(self): self.variable = self.textbox.get_text()`, with the "textbox" in "on_textbox_activated" being the name of your textbox widget without the self prefix. As for your label, I am pretty sure you can use `set_text('text here')`, so `self.label.set_text(self.variable)`.

see http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtklabel.html for the label if the set_text does not work.